# PHP SQL Query: how to select same Ids?

Tags: php, sql, database, select

My code is:

```
$vote = DB::SELECT(DB::RAW("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE product_id = product_id; "));
```

Here[1] is a screenshot of my DB.

I'd like to ask how to select the same Producut Id in the SQL Query?

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Jvc.png

Comment: `SELECT * FROM votes WHERE product_id = 5`?

Comment: What do you mean _"the same"_ as what???

Comment: `Producut Id` the same as what???

Comment: @u_mulder Would like to count all the votes. So I'm going to get all the same product ids

Comment: `SELECT SUM(vote) FROM votes WHERE product_id = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count sum of votes for each product and sort sum of votes from highest to lowest, then your query is:

```
SELECT 
    product_id, SUM(vote) as `vote_rate` 
FROM 
    votes 
GROUP BY 
    product_id 
ORDER BY 
    `vote_rate` DESC
```